# Сделать на сайте кнопку Добавить на главный экран?

Tags: android, wordpress, google-chrome

В мобильном хроме (андроид) есть стандартная опция в меню Добавить на гл. экран. Ярлык-ссылку любого сайта или страницы таким образом можно добавить на рабочий стол смартфона. Подскажите, как это реализовать на сайте (wordpress) через кнопку/ссылку?

Т.е. по сути нужно продублировать стандартную функцию хрома, типа что-то вроде кнопки Поделиться. Интересует именно простой ярлык-ссылка сайта, при нажатии на которую открывается хром и загружается сайт. Видел информацию по PWA, а вот как простой ярлык реализовать - ничего в сети не нашел.

Comment: PWA - бесполезная фигня (разве что это предложение может показать. И то не всем). Если хочешь чтобы было по уму - надо писать/делать нативное приложение. Причём не на webview, если интересует попадание в маркеты.